# Credit union error on paperwork

Tags: property, divorce, legal-research, banking

Can a credit union be held liable for leaving off an account holder on a savings account? A friend is getting a divorce and just found out all her savings was placed into an account with only her soon to be ex's name. They were married when they opened the account together at the same time.

Comment: Your friend a) should get a lawyer, if she hasn't already and b) should ask that lawyer about how property division works in your jurisdiction. *In general*, the name(s) on the account are not significant when considering whether it should be divided in divorce, but this may vary from place to place.

Answer (score 2):

The credit union probably cannot be sued in this case, because there is no harm.

One of the main purposes of a divorce is to divide the property of the couple (at least the property acquired during the marriage) in a manner that ignores formal ownership of and title to that property.

The fact that a savings account is in, for example, a husband's name, does not prevent a savings account containing post-marital funds from being equitably divided between the spouses upon divorce in the same way that a joint savings account might be divided upon divorce.